# WildFly overlay file locations

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I've just started working with overlays in WildFly and it's clear they are going to be very valuable for our process.  It appears however that the overlay source files **have** to be in a directory below JBOSS_HOME (d:\wildfly\bin in my windows instance).  If I specify any path in my --content parameter, it makes it relative to JBOSS_HOME.  (ex. **--content=/myfiles/filename.properties=WEB-INF/classes/filename.properties** looks for filename.properties in d:\wildfly\bin\myfiles)
Is there any way to reference paths outside of JBOSS_HOME in the WildFly CLI?  (The same restriction appears to apply to deployment source files.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like this is simpler than I thought.  Paths are not relative to jboss_home, but to the directory from which jboss-cli.bat is called.  If I call the .bat file (or presumably the .sh on my linux servers) from a different location, I can place my overlay files and deployment files in that location.